# How do I render a react component only after a state is set?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My app fetches some data from a server using `useEffect` and passes it as a prop to a child component. I would like to pause the rendering of the child component until the data is completely fetched and loaded into a `state`. How can I achieve this?

My code(simplified):

```js
const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(undefined)
  
  useEffect(async () => {
    const fetchedData = await getDataFromServer()
    setData(fetchedData)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <ChildComponent data={data} /> // How to pause rendering until data != undefined?
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a ternary operator, since `undefined` is a falsy value the condition will return `false` and it will show `Loading...` until the `data` is fetched and after it is done fetching the condition will become `true` since `data` is no longer `undefined` i.e. `falsy` that's how the `data` will be passed to the child component only after it is fetched.

```
const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(undefined)
  
  useEffect(async () => {
    const fetchedData = await getDataFromServer()
    setData(fetchedData)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      {data ? <ChildComponent data={data} /> : <p>Loading...</p>}
    </div>
  )
}
```

More on `falsy` values [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

More on `ternary operator` in Javascript [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)